# Adding object of one class to the arraylist in another class

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I have two java class,mostly constructors such as getter and setters.

```
ReportGroup.java

  String ReportGroupName;
  List<ReportInfo> reportList; //getter & setter

ReportInfo.java

  String ReportName;
  String ReportId;
  String ReportPath; //getter&setter
```

I have set all the values in ReportInfo and ReportGroupName in ReportGroup.Is there any possible way where I can add the values of ReportInfo to the List in ReportGroup( List reportList)

public class test {

```
public static List<ReportInfo> reportInfo = new ArrayList<ReportInfo>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String orgId="346";
    String orgName="Ralph Lauren Corporation";

    String reportPath= "/"+orgId +"_"+orgName.replaceAll(" ","_");
    String reportFolderPath = "C:/Lokesh/Dev Tools/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/ROOT/Reports";
    List<String> filesArray = null;
    filesArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    String filetowrite="C:/Users/lbandhu/Desktop/test.html";
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(filetowrite);


    ReportGroup reportGroup=new ReportGroup();
    reportGroup.setReportGroupName(orgName);
     reportGroup.getReportList().addAll(reportInfo);
    File folder = new File(reportFolderPath+reportPath);

    List<String> reportNames =  listFolder(folder);



    for (String rname : reportNames) {
        ReportInfo reportInfo=new ReportInfo();
        reportInfo.setReportName(rname);

        folder = new File(reportFolderPath+reportPath+"/"+rname);
        System.out.println(folder);
        fw.write("<br><tr> "+rname +" Utilization Reports</tr><br>");
        Iterator<String> iterator=listFilesForFolder(folder, filesArray).iterator();
        writeReportPath( fw,iterator, reportFolderPath,reportInfo);
        fw.write("<br>");

    }

    filesArray.clear();

    fw.close();

 private static void writeReportPath(FileWriter fw,Iterator<String> iterator, String   reportFolderPath,ReportInfo reportInfo) throws IOException
{

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String listofFiles=iterator.next();

        StringBuilder strgfile=new StringBuilder(listofFiles);
        String filename=strgfile.substring(strgfile.indexOf("/")+1);

        //System.out.println("name" +filename);
        String[] split = filename.split("_");

                if(split.length > 1) {
                    if(split[0].contains("MONTHLY")) {
                        //System.out.println(split[1].substring(0, 3) + " " + split[2]);
                        String monthly=split[1]+ " " + split[2];
                        int index=monthly.indexOf('/');
                        String reportId=monthly.substring(0, index);
                        //ReportInfo reportInfo=new ReportInfo();
                        //List <ReportInfo> reportGroup=new ArrayList<ReportInfo>();
                        reportInfo.setReportId(reportId);
                        reportInfo.setReportPath(reportFolderPath + "/" + strgfile);


                       fw.write("<br><tr><a href="+"\"" + reportFolderPath + "/" + strgfile+"\""+"/>"
                       +reportId+"</a></tr>");
                    }
                    else {
                        for(int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
                            //String org=+rname;
                            String title2=split[i] + " ";


                        }
                        //System.out.println("");
                  }
                }
                else {

                     fw.write("<br>"+"<h>"+filename +"</h>"+"<br>");
                }
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reportGroup.getReportList().add(reportInfo)
```

or

```
reportGroup.getReportList().addAll(reportInfos)
```

Comment: This requires an instance of both `ReportGroup` and `ReportInfo`.

Answer (score -1):

```
ReportInfo info = new ReportInfo();
// Do whatever is needed with the info object
```

If you want the same list to be accessible from anywhere, it needs to be static.

```
public static List<ReportInfo> reportList = new List<ReportInfo>();
```

This means that the values stored inside `reportList`  will not differ for each individual object you create for it. You can then use `ReportGroup.reportList.add(info)`

Otherwise, make an object of `ReportGroup`, just make sure that you make `reportList` public

```
ReportGroup group = new ReportGroup();
group.reportList.add(info);
```

Comment: No, they way his classes are structured he doesn't want static access, nor does it make sense to make it static.

Comment: @JoshM Therefore, I added the second option... Please read the full answer before down voting or leaving a negative comment

Comment: @SamTebbs33 You may have added a second option, but the `static` part doesn't make any more sense than before.

Comment: I have updated with some code for better understanding of the situation.